# Serially process ConcurrentQueue and limit to one message processor. Correct pattern?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, concurrency

I'm building a multithreaded app in .net.

I have a thread that listens to a connection (abstract, serial, tcp...).

When it receives a new message, it adds it to via AddMessage.  Which then call startSpool.  startSpool checks to see if the spool is already running and if it is, returns, otherwise, starts it in a new thread.  The reason for this is, the messages HAVE to be processed serially, FIFO.

So, my questions are...
Am I going about this the right way?
Are there better, faster, cheaper patterns out there?

My apologies if there is a typo in my code, I was having problems copying and pasting.

```
    ConcurrentQueue<IMyMessage > messages = new ConcurrentQueue<IMyMessage>();

    const int maxSpoolInstances = 1;

    object lcurrentSpoolInstances;
    int currentSpoolInstances = 0;

    Thread spoolThread;

    public void AddMessage(IMyMessage message)
    {
        this.messages.Add(message);

        this.startSpool();
    }

    private void startSpool()
    {
        bool run = false;

        lock (lcurrentSpoolInstances)
        {
            if (currentSpoolInstances <= maxSpoolInstances)
            {
                this.currentSpoolInstances++;
                run = true;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        if (run)
        {
            this.spoolThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(spool));
            this.spoolThread.Start();
        }
    }

    private void spool()
    {
        Message.ITimingMessage message;

        while (this.messages.Count > 0)
        {
            // TODO: Is this below line necessary or does the TryDequeue cover this?
            message = null;

            this.messages.TryDequeue(out message);

            if (message != null)
            {
                // My long running thing that does something with this message.
            }
        }


        lock (lcurrentSpoolInstances)
        {
            this.currentSpoolInstances--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The queue will be FIFO but if you have multiple threads filling it, how would you know that the _IN's_ are in the right order?

Comment: @AustinSalonen The description of the problem suggests that there is a single producer thread adding items (ie: from a TCP connection), and a separate consumer thread.  This is a classic FIFO producer/consumer scenario...

Comment: You have a ug in your `startSpool` method. You never increment `currentSpoolInstances`, so every call to `startSpool` will start a new thread. You need to increment `currentSpoolInstances` before releasing the lock.

Comment: @JimMischel - Correct.  I fixed the problem.  It was a transcribing problem, RE: Unable to copy and paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be easier using `BlockingCollection<T>` instead of `ConcurrentQueue<T>`.

Something like this should work:

```
class MessageProcessor : IDisposable
{
    BlockingCollection<IMyMessage> messages = new BlockingCollection<IMyMessage>();

    public MessageProcessor()
    {
       // Move this to constructor to prevent race condition in existing code (you could start multiple threads...
       Task.Factory.StartNew(this.spool, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    public void AddMessage(IMyMessage message)
    {
        this.messages.Add(message);
    }

    private void Spool()
    {
         foreach(IMyMessage message in this.messages.GetConsumingEnumerable())
         {
               // long running thing that does something with this message.
         }
    }

    public void FinishProcessing()
    {
         // This will tell the spooling you're done adding, so it shuts down
         this.messages.CompleteAdding();
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        this.FinishProcessing();
    }
}
```

---

Edit: If you wanted to support multiple consumers, you could handle that via a separate constructor.  I'd refactor this to:

```
    public MessageProcessor(int numberOfConsumers = 1)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<numberOfConsumers;++i)
            StartConsumer();
    }

    private void StartConsumer()
    {
       // Move this to constructor to prevent race condition in existing code (you could start multiple threads...
       Task.Factory.StartNew(this.spool, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }
```

This would allow you to start any number of consumers.  Note that this breaks the rule of having it be strictly FIFO - the processing will potentially process "numberOfConsumer" elements in blocks with this change.

Multiple *producers* are already supported.  The above is thread safe, so any number of threads can call `Add(message)` in parallel, with no changes.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  You identified a race condition, could you provide a bit more detail about how it could start 2 threads?

Comment: @MichaelRice If you wanted to start multiple consumers, you could just pass that in as a constructor parameter:

Comment: @MichaelRice Edited to show you how to support any number of consumer threads.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, or I'm misunderstanding your response.

In your code comment "// Move this to constructor to prevent race condition in existing code (you could start multiple threads..."

Could you detail how the race condition could occur?  I'm not seeing it.

Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelRice Oh - in your code, you're not showing where you set currentSpoolInstances - without that being set properly inside the lock, you potentially open up a race condition.

Comment: Edited.  Race condition fixed?

Comment: @MichaelRice Yes, mostly - though you still have the possibility of having a "spool" end at the same time as an item is added, and the item left sitting there never processed...

Answer (score 1):

I think that Reed's answer is the best way to go, but for the sake of academics, here is an example using the concurrent queue -- you had some races in the code that you posted (depending upon how you handle incrementing currnetSpoolInstances)

The changes I made (below) were:

- Switched to a Task instead of a Thread (uses thread pool instead of incurring the cost of creating a new thread)
- added the code to increment/decrement your spool instance count
- changed the "if currentSpoolInstances <= max ... to just < to avoid having one too many workers (probably just a typo)
- changed the way that empty queues were handled to avoid a race:  I think you had a race, where your while loop could have tested false, (you thread begins to exit), but at that moment, a new item is added (so your spool thread is exiting, but your spool count > 0, so your queue stalls).

```
private ConcurrentQueue<IMyMessage> messages = new ConcurrentQueue<IMyMessage>();

const int maxSpoolInstances = 1;
object lcurrentSpoolInstances = new object();
int currentSpoolInstances = 0;

public void AddMessage(IMyMessage message)
{
    this.messages.Enqueue(message);
    this.startSpool();
}

private void startSpool()
{
    lock (lcurrentSpoolInstances)
    {
        if (currentSpoolInstances < maxSpoolInstances)
        {
            this.currentSpoolInstances++;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(spool, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        }
    }
}

private void spool()
{
    IMyMessage message;
    while (true)
    {
// you do not need to null message because it is an "out" parameter, had it been a "ref" parameter, you would want to null it.

        if(this.messages.TryDequeue(out message))
        {
            // My long running thing that does something with this message. 
        }
        else
        {
            lock (lcurrentSpoolInstances)
            {
                if (this.messages.IsEmpty)
                {
                    this.currentSpoolInstances--;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check 'Pipelines pattern': http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963548.aspx

- Use BlockingCollection for the 'buffers'.
- Each Processor (e.g. ReadStrings, CorrectCase, ..), should run in a Task.

[image]

HTH..